# Loading complete Html-page in contentpane of aspx-page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

here at home I have different projects and libraries for which I've created an helpfile with Sandcastle.
Now Sandcastle provides also the possibility to create a website.

What I would like to do is to create an aspx-page where I can dynamically create a menu and where the existing helpfile-websites can be sollicited. All in one place.

Is it possible to accomplish this? Maybe some control that I can use to view an entire webpage?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Seems I can't get it to work in an ASP-page for whatever reason, but probably because of the way Sandcastle creates the help-pages.
I've now tried it with a WinForm-application with a webbrowser-control and this approach works, so I guess this will be the way I have to go here.

But I do need to say thanks to Alison (and Leon) for their help regarding this issue.
Their solution works for "normal" html-pages, but (unfortunately) not for the ones I have.
For that reason, I've accepted the answer so others could benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

Take a look at [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/). You can have a div on your page and load the html from an external page into it.  The load function can grab individual pieces of HTML from a different page.

On your main page, add this html:

```
<div id="myexternalpage"></div>
```

On the different page, add a div tag with an id around the content you want to grab like:

```
<div id="myexternalcontent">Test</div>
```

The add the following to your head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myexternalpage').load('myexternalpage.html #content');
})
</script>
```

Notice the addition of the "@content" selector to the end of the load function?  This will have jQuery load the different page and return only the content in the div with id="content".

Using jQuery load will let you load the content once the page loads and you won't need to use any iFrames.  You can use CSS to handle the height/width and handle any overflow.

Comment: Can I just load the entire page like this, or do I need to take only the HTML inbetween the <body>-tags of the page?

Comment: The previous code would have returned the entire HTML of the page.  I've updated the code to only return HTML contained within a specific div.

Comment: I've taken a closer look at the files generated by Sandcastle and it seems it uses IFrames itself (it's build msdn-like style). The url shown in the browser never changes, although I can navigate between the different pages. So my guess is that I do need to load the whole page (which contains scripts too) but I'm affraid that there will be conflicts of html-tags that should not be nested (like a form tag or something like that).

Comment: Have you tested yet?  It sounds like this might be a working solution.  What happens when you test on a few pages?  Do you encounter errors/problems?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a quick and dirty test-page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js " ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { $('#myexternalpage').load('WebHelp/KoenHoefman/ExhangeRateWebService/Index.html'); }) 
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="myexternalpage">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get an error on the script line.

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

Do I have to replace `document` with something (probably a stupid question but I'm not used to use javascript)?

**Update:**
Added Leon's code and now it shows something. But when I want to use the page I really want to show (which is located in a subfolder) I get only the items on the index.html. The page that should be loaded into the IFrame of that page isn't shown. Also the pictures that are located in the same folder are not shown.

> Error:  HTTP 404
>   Requested URL:
>   /html/aea04102-3d0d-cf0d-f5f4-5634f5f06aed.htm

Comment: Where's the reference to the jQuery.js? You need that above where you're using the jQuery call.
You can use Google's CDN: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with Index.htm.  What kind of page is it?  What is on the page?

Comment: It's a page populated by Sandcastle. It's kind of like a MSDN-style website, populated from the XML-documentation in my solution.
On the right side there's a treeview with the namesspaces and the class-structure. On the left side there's an IFrame in which the
different pages are loaded. These pages are located in a subdirectory, as are the scripts, the css...
So It seems to me that the current aspx-page (Test2.aspx) is looking for those files in one of it's subdirectories instead of in 
a subdirectory of the folder of index.html.